# Rendering to dynamic outlets

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to make a list of items that when clicked, shows an edit form inline with the list item.

So far this is what I've tried:

router.js.coffee

```coffeescript
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'friend_management', ->
    @resource 'groups', ->
      @resource 'group', path: '/:group_id', ->
        @route 'edit'
```

templates/groups.hbs

```handlebars
<div id="group-list">
  {{#each}}
    {{#view Dfw.GroupView}}
      {{link-to name 'group.edit' this class=cssClass tagName='div'}}
      {{outlet groupEditOutletName}}
    {{/view}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
<!-- it works fine if there is one outlet rendered here,
     but I would prefer the outlet for the edit form rendered inline -->
```

templates/group/edit.hbs

```handlebars
{{input type='text' value=name placeholder="Group name"}}
<button {{action update}}>Update Group</button>
```

routes/group/edit.js.coffee

```coffeescript
App.GroupEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  renderTemplate: (controller, model)->
    @render('group/edit', outlet: "group#{model.id}", into: 'groups')
```

I get the impression that Ember.js doesn't allow for dynamic named outlets, but does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have would be to place the editing UI that you want to be placed inline as part of the actual view.  This would remove the ability to have the action still be router based, so you wouldn't be able to have group/edit/ID, but you would be able to edit inline.

```
Dfw.GroupView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'groupView', // or whatever you call it
  isEditing: false,
  click: function(evt) {
    if (!this.get('isEditing')) {
      this.set('isEditing', true);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    update: function (e) {
      // Update code here
      this.set('isEditing', false);
    }
});
```

Then your template for the group view could be something like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=cssClass}}>
  <!-- HTML that will be shown even when not editing goes here -->
  {{#if view.isEditing}}
    {{input type='text' value=name placeholder="Group name"}}
    <button {{action view.update}}>Update Group</button>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

I hope this helps.  While it does not use the routing, it seems as though using routing in this case wouldnt make much sense, because you are viewing all of the objects together, instead of viewing one of them and then clicking edit.

Good luck!

Comment: I got your approach to work. It is not quite what I was looking for, but it does work. I don't really need to have the URL represent an editing state. Thank you very much for the response.